# Proving two reparameterizations by arclength differ only by a sign and constant

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Let $\alpha(t)$ be a regular curve. Prove that if $\beta(s)$ and $\gamma(\bar{s})$  are two reparameterizations by arclength, then $s = \pm\bar{s} +a$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

I know that the following must be true:

$||(\alpha(\beta(s)))'||=||\alpha'(\beta(s))\cdot\beta'(s)|| = 1$

$||(\alpha(\gamma(\bar{s})))'||=||\alpha'(\gamma(\bar{s}))\cdot\gamma'(\bar{s})|| = 1$

But I don't know where to go from there. Where do I start? I'd appreciate any help.

**EDIT**: Well, from what I wrote above, it's now obvious to me that:

$|\beta'(s)| = |\gamma'(\bar{s})| \Rightarrow \beta'(s) = \pm \gamma'(\bar{s}) \Rightarrow \beta(s) = \pm\gamma(\bar{s}) + a$

Is this correct? It doesn't appear to be in the exact way the exercise wanted me to get to, but they are equivalent, right?

**EDIT 2**: I now see that I've done exactly what the exercise asked. It's just a matter of notation.

Comment: The word you want is “sign,” not “signal.”

Comment: @JackLee Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit in the statement $s=\bar s + a$ is that they lead to the same point in $t$ parameter space, $t=\beta(s) = \gamma(\bar s)$. At such points we indeed have $|\beta'(s)| = |\gamma'(\bar s)| = 1$ for all such $s， \bar s $, by your computation.

As regular parameterisations cannot change sign, the sign of one $s,\bar s$ pair determines the sign of the derivative, and $\{\beta'(s),\gamma'(s')\} = \{ 1\},\{-1\},$ or $\{1,-1\}$. This accounts for the $±$ but they are all proven the same way, so say $\beta'(s)=\gamma'(\bar s) = 1$. Then for any $s$, integration reveals
$$ \beta(s) = s + c_1$$
and for any $\bar s$,
$$ \gamma(\bar s) = \bar s + c_2$$
$\beta(s) = \gamma(\bar s)$ then rewrites to $s = \bar s + (c_2 - c_1)$ as needed. The proof clearly extends to the other cases.